# how to use same container view in multiple storyboards?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, container-view

I want to create an application which shows list of features when user taps on right navigation item. This 'Show list of features' screen will cover half of the iPhone screen with slide animation while hiding and showing it on screen. When user taps on any future from feature list it will navigate user to new screen which will have also have this 'show list of features' button as right navigation item instead of back button.

To create show list of features UI, can I use ContainerView in Xcode? ContainerView UI will be same for all the screens. How can I reuse the same containerView in multiple storyboards?

Thanks!

Comment: This should help https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

Comment: @gurmandeep Your link doesn't answer it, as it doesn't explain multiple storyboards situation.

Comment: Why you want to use multiple storyboards? There should be one storyboard with multiple view controllers. Thats how container works. One parent controller and multiple child